# How to load more items when scroll reached the end of gridview using Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using grid view to show images. The problem is I have lots of images and I don't want to load all of them at the start. What is the best way of accessing the server to fetch more items once the `GridView` has reached the end?

Comment: Please show us your attempt and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use Recycler view - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Leslie has said, you can use RecyclerView +[FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Android-API) to achieve your goal, I have made a [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/RecycleView_FFimageLoading) which will load 300 pictures.

And you can also use Glide to load the picture, I have included both Glide and FFImageLoading in the demo.

Comment: Is ffImageLoading available for native android though?

Comment: Hi,@G.hakim, yes, see my demo.